# PHP - delete content after and before specific tag

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I need to remove specific tags and text between them. For tags I can use `str_replace` but for text between I try using `preg_replace` but nothing works.

Code to fix:

```
// ...
[tabs_item title=”My title”] some different text here... [/tabs_item]
[tabs_item title=”My Other title”] some different text here... [/tabs_item]
// ...
```

my code:

```
$pattern = "/[tabs_item[^>]*title=\"my txt\"](.*?)[\\/tabs_item]/si";
$replacement = '';
$fix1 = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content2);

$search  = array('[/tabs_item]');
$replace = array('');
$fix2 = str_replace($search, $replace, $fix1);

return $fix2;
```

Comment: you have `”` in your "code to fix". Those aren't valid quotes for html(ish) text. don't run your stuff through a wordprocessor - it'll mangle code like there's no tomorrow. use a proper text/code editor.

Comment: Why using `[^>]*` in your pattern?

Comment: What is your expected output? Is it "some different text here..."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for posting full code.  This needs to be handled a little differently since there is html in your content.

First, because your content contains the / char, we need to change the regex delimiter to something else so it doesn't interfere.  I changed it to %.  Next, since you're using a multi-line string, we need to set a modifier on the regex to include newline chars in the .(dot: all chars).  This modifier is added by adding the 's' to the end of your pattern after the closing delimiter.

This code is tested and worked for me.

```
$content = '
   <p>[tabs] [tabs_item title="Description"]<br />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
   <p>[/tabs_item] [tabs_item title="Zwroty"]</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce nec mauris nunc. Vestibulum elit urna, aliquet et urna et, sagittis blandit ligula.</p>
   [/tabs_item]
   <p>[tabs_item title="Peyment and shipping"]</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
   <p><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet " <a href="#" target="_blank">url</a>"</p>
   <p>[/tabs_item]</p>
   <p>[/tabs]</p>';

$pattern = "%\[tabs_item[^\[]+\[/tabs_item\]%s";
$replacement = '';
$out = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);

echo $out;
```

Results in:

```
<p>[tabs]  
   <p></p>
   <p>[/tabs]</p>
```

To answer your followup question:  If you want to remove only this tag:

[tabs_item title="Peyment and shipping"]...[/tabs_item]

you can change your pattern to:

```
$pattern = '%\[tabs_item title="Peyment and shipping"\][^\[]+\[/tabs_item\]%s';
```

Which results in:

```
<p>[tabs] [tabs_item title="Description"]<br />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
   <p>[/tabs_item] [tabs_item title="Zwroty"]</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce nec mauris nunc. Vestibulum elit urna, aliquet et urna et, sagittis blandit ligula.</p>
   [/tabs_item]
   <p></p>
   <p>[/tabs]</p>
```

Comment: I have error: Warning: preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in

Comment: I forgot to add the delimiter.  I updated my answer.  Hope that helps.

Comment: No error this time, but also with no effect ;/ I've post my full code

Comment: Having html in your content makes a difference for how you handle regex.  I updated my answer.

Comment: you are awesome :-) It works! I have one more questions, how patter should looks like to only remove `[tabs_item title="Peyment and shipping"]...[/tabs_item]`

Comment: My pleasure.  I updated my answer to include your followup question.

Answer (score 0):

If you no have regexp skill you can make this with explode function like this;

```
<?php

$var = '// something
[tabs_item title=”My title”] some different text here... [/tabs_item]
[tabs_item title=”My Other title”] some different text here... [/tabs_item]
// something';

$first = explode('[tabs_item title=”My title”]',$var);
$start = $first[0];
$last = explode('[/tabs_item]',$first[1]);
$end = $last[count($last)-1];
echo $start.$end;

?>
```

Comment: I tried that - but it does't work properly, it remove the entire contents of both before [tabs_item title = "My title"] and after [/ tabs_item] also ;/

Comment: @AQ404 also do you need between of the tag ? Actually that code works like on your question what you need part.

Comment: my full php code (php + wordpress) with your suggestion

`<?php
function replace_content($content) {
 $first = explode('[tabs_item title=”Zwroty”]', $content);
 $start = $first[0];
 $last = explode('[/tabs_item]',$first[1]);
 $end = $last[count($last)-1];
 $content = $start.$end;
 return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','replace_content');
?>` doesn't work

Comment: http://pastebin.com/s01KVrDZ I'm testing like that and seems working.If your expectation is different please give me detail.

Comment: on your example it works correctly, but when I put it on a server with the actual data it stops working

Comment: Can you share actual data for my tests ?